# Firewall settings in linux for remote mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, tcp, firewall

I am trying to connect a remote mysql database in my local application. But it was not connecting with the given user name and password. Though I gave the `GRANT ALL` to that user. After a long study I came to know about firewall. I assume the following rules of firewall is the culprit for not connecting:

```
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Please let me know if I am right. And please suggest me a solution to overcome this.

Comment: what ip addresses/networks do you want to allow connections from?

Comment: 103.19.252.xx is my ip address. I want to allow this @pala_

Comment: Totally off-topic, because unrelated to programming. Also, I googled the title of the question and immediately got proper results. Also, there is official documentation that specifies what you need to do. Also, most major linux distros even have firewall admin tools allowing you to permit MySQL with but a single click.

Comment: also, this should be downvoted for not trying to describe the error the user sees. Also, I removed all "thanks in advance" chattery, as it distracts from the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poke a hole in your firewall, to your given IP address by running the following (as root)

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 --src 103.19.252/24 -j ACCEPT`

`-I INPUT` signifies we are looking at incoming traffic
`--dport 3306` means any traffic headed for port `3306` (mysql)
`--src 103.19.252/24` will open up the connection to any traffic that originates from the `103.19.252.xx` subnet
`-j ACCEPT` means let it through
You'll also need to make sure your MySQL user is allowed to connect from that ip

Comment: Running as sudo may be necessary.